# i am trying to make a function that returns price excluding vat

Tags: python

In the below code I am trying to return price excluding VAT.

I am passing in price including VAT as 'incl'.
I am trying to work with a VAT amount of 15 instead of 15% as that is how it is stored on the database I work with.

Can someone please explain why the below does not return 85? try as I might it returns 100 time after time.

```
def lessvat(incl,vat):
    
    vat_perc = vat / 100
    diff = incl * vat_perc 
    return( incl - diff )
    


print(lessvat(100,15))
```

I'm new to this...

thanks

Comment: this code returns `85.0` for me

Comment: @manzet Same for me!

Comment: According to your print statement it looks like you're using Python3, but that behaviour will happen if you're using Python 2 (because `vat/100` will result in `0`). Try `vat / 100.0` and see what happens

Comment: Oh wow!!! That makes complete sense! thanks for the quick help guys (:

Comment: `85  × 1.15 != 100`. Your formular is wrong. Try `incl / (1.0 + (vat / 100.0))`